# Server - side validation is not working.

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, server-side, code-behind

I am trying to do server side validation when the next button is clicked on my second step of my wizard control.

When I click the next button, my validation's appear to show my two textboxes are valid but, then it skips to the next step anyway. Both the phone and zipcode are required.

The comment box needs to be checked to make sure it doesn't contain more then 200 values. I can't figure out why it goes to the next step when my two validation controls are not valid.

Below is my code for my validation controls for these twp text boxes and the code for my code behind for when the next button is clicked. This code works for the first step of the wizard  Here is a link to the site so you can see what happens.   http://scort323.csweb.kutztown.edu/Assign3/assign3.aspx

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelPhone" runat="server" Text="*Phone:" CssClass="LabelText"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPhone" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="phoneRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter your phone number."
                CssClass="errorMessage" ControlToValidate="TextBoxPhone" Text="*" SetFocusOnError="true"
                Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="infoGroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="phoneRegularExpressionValidator" runat="server"
                ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid phone number(xxx-xxx-xxxx)." ControlToValidate="TextBoxPhone"
                ValidationExpression="\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}" Text="*" CssClass="errorMessage" SetFocusOnError="true"
                Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="infoGroup"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelZip" runat="server" Text="*Zip Code:" CssClass="LabelText"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxZip" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="zipRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter your zip code."
                CssClass="errorMessage" ControlToValidate="TextBoxZip" Text="*" SetFocusOnError="true"
                Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="infoGroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="zipRegularExpressionValidator" runat="server"
                ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid zip code(5 digits)." ControlToValidate="TextBoxZip"
                ValidationExpression="\d{5}" Text="*" CssClass="errorMessage" SetFocusOnError="true"
                Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="infoGroup"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>

protected void Wizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender,WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex;
    int length = TextBoxComments.Text.Length;
    Page.Validate("infoGroup");
    if(index == 1)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            if (length <= 200)
            {
                Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = index + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = index;
            }
        }
        Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = index +1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = index + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = index;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This step should be inside your if condition that checks page validity. is not it?

```
Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = index +1;
```

Or it should be:

```
 if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        if (length <= 200)
        {
            Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = index + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = index;
        }

    }
    Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = index;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try cancelling the nextbutton click until the wizard is validated.

```
protected void Wizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
  {
    e.Cancel = !ValidateWizardStep(e.NextStepIndex);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to validate with jQuery OR JavaScript. I think it's better than server side validation.

always try to do validation on client side because it gives you better performance, compatible and many good flexible functionality with that